# CentOS 6.4 minimal unable to use yum

Tags: virtualbox, centos, fedora, yum

I have a minimal CentOS 6.4 running off a VM through VirtualBox in Bridged mode. Fedora 19 is the host. I am completely unable to use yum update. Whenever I try, I get this error:

Error: Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: extras

I tried googling extensively for an answer, but none of the suggestions (like try yum clean all, use google DNS, or uncomment #base= line in /etc/yum.repos.d/ files) are making any difference.

Please help me resolve this headache.

Answer (score 0):

To rule out a problem with the extras repositories you can do

```
yum update --disablerepo=extras
```

This will only disable extras for a single instance of yum.

If you want to make this permanent you could add

```
enabled=0
```

to the `[extras]` section of /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo.  When I do this I place the    `enabled=0` after the `gpgcheck=1` line of the repos section I wish to disable.  In this case enabling it per instance is the opposite of the first option above, e.g.

```
yum update --enablerepo=extras
```

These instructions are assuming your internet connection is active and your CentOS 6.4 install has a valid IP address (displayed using `ifconfig`).